# IVs in proportion

Tags: regression

I send different versions of text to different recipients, but I have no way of knowing who gets which. I do however know what proportion of users get which text, so for example I know that, on Date *d*, *n<sub>d,i</sub>* of the people got text *t<sub>d,i</sub>*, for *i=1,2,..,m<sub>d</sub>*, where *n<sub>d,i</sub>* is in [0,1]. Texts are repeated over multiple days, so *t<sub>1,1</sub>* might equal *t<sub>2,3</sub>*. (Or I can rename the *i*s so they're equal of course.)

I want to regress the continuous DV *y*, outcome of the text-sending, against that breakdown, so I know which individual texts have a higher/lower *y*. (I don't care about the time-series aspect of *d*.) Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't find this clear on what an observation (case, record) is in your data. (A concrete example is often much clearer than a bunch of notation.)

But if I understand this correctly you have a bunch of predictors $n_{d, i}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{m_d} n_{d, i} = 1$. (Perhaps you have other predictors too.)

I see no problem with using that bunch in a model, except to note that one of the $n_{d, i}$ is redundant given the constraint to sum to $1$.

I would see this as resembling in one sense any binary predictor with two states  which would be coded as a single indicator (dummy, in a common but uncouth terminology) variable, or any categorical predictor with several states which can be coded with one fewer indicator variables.

Picky detail: Unless it is somehow standard in your field, I wouldn't use  $n$ to denote proportions; the convention that $n$ means sample size or (less commonly) a counted variable is quite strong.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll try that, it sounds reasonable. (As far as the *n* notation, I originally wrote the question above with the n(d,i)s as subpopulations rather than proportions. Hence the letter *n*.)

Comment: Also I'm not sure how uncouth "dummy" is but you should know it is not only used in statistics. It has a similar meaning in bridge, for example.

Comment: An objection to dummy is that it has overtones of stupid. I have real stories of its use being wildly misread as offensive.

Comment: Two downvotes now for an accepted answer, and no explanation or alternative answer anywhere in sight.